# Memory usage skyrocketting while reading Parquet file from S3 with Polars

Tags: python, docker, amazon-s3, parquet, python-polars

I try to read multiple Parquet files from S3. I read using Polars and Pyarrow with the following command :

```
pl.scan_pyarrow_dataset(ds.dataset(f"my_bucket/myfiles/",filesystem=s3)).collect()
```

There is 4 files in the folder, with the following sizes : 120MB, 102MB, 85MB, 75MB

I then run my code inside Docker container (inside Airflow task to be precise, but I don't think it's important here). When reading, the memory consumption on Docker Desktop can go as high as 10GB, and it's only for 4 relatively small files.

Is it an expected behaviour with Parquet files ? The file is 6M rows long, with some texts but really shorts.

I will soon have to read bigger files, like 600 or 700 MB, will it be possible in the same configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

Parquet files are compressed so when you load them in memory they take more space than they do on disk. You're getting about 4:1 (oops should be 20:1). There are really two things going on. You've got the data which is probably like 5:1 compression. On top of that you've got a bunch of pointers and open file connections to put things together which takes more memory. If you're really going to just `collect` it all then see if leaving out `pyarrow` helps

You can do something like (obviously I can't test this against your s3 account).

```
pl.concat([pl.read_parquet(x, storage_options=s3.storage_options) for x in s3.ls(f"my_bucket/myfiles/")])
```

If that doesn't help then the thing to do is not `collect` until after you run whatever analysis/expressions on the data. The benefit of lazyframes (the result of `scan_xxxxx` is that you don't load all the data upfront. You only load/stream the data as it's needed. This may or may not be enough to work with bigger than memory data but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Seems to be more like a 20:1 no ? Files are 500MB and memory go up to 10GB.

Comment: Sorry a combination of lazily adding in my head and miss reading 10 as 1 and then big rounding did me in pretty badly there.

Comment: Even 10 to 1 isn't unusual. You can check what memory polars is using by calling https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.estimated_size.html#polars.DataFrame.estimated_size You can also call this on each column to get a better idea of where the issue comes from.